# How to inline JSON object as map of attributes and values for component?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to write the following as JSX?

```
var settings = {setting1: 1, setting: 2};
MyComponent(setting)
```

I tried `<MyComponent {settings} />` but this does not compile. So the only way seems to be as follows:

```
<MyComponent setting1={settings.setting1} setting2={settings.setting2} />
```

which will be very noisy if there are a lot props.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, the best way is to drop down to plain JS:

```
<div>
  {MyComponent(settings)}
</div>
```

In the next version of React, you'll be able to write `<MyComponent {...settings} />`, like the ES6 array spread operator.

Answer (score 3):

```
var settings = {setting1: 1, setting: 2};    
<MyComponent settings={settings} />
```

Then in the component you can just access it with

```
this.props.settings.setting1
```

or

```
this.props.settings.setting2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a JSON object in as props which just looks like

`<MyComponent settings={settings} />`

Then inside the component you just call `this.props.settings` to access it.

Comment: Sure, but thats not the same cause now I have to use `this.props.settings.settings1` instead of `this.props.settings1`.